# Exploratory Factor Analysis loading factor

Tags: factor-analysis

This is my first time doing a factor analysis and I am not very familiar with this topic.
First, special thanks to https://youtu.be/xKl4LJAXnEA

I am trying to do a exploratory factor analysis on data with 54 attributes, all ranged from 0 to 4.
The data can be found on https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Divorce+Predictors+data+set#

I basically followed all the steps from the above YouTube video. My data passed all the adequacy tests (like sampling adequacy, normality test) at the preparing step but I used a two-factor analysis instead of 3 on the video.
When I ran the EFA, the loading factor output with cutoff = 0.3, my output is:

> print(twofactor2$loadings, cutoff = 0.3)

Loadings:
      ML1    ML2
Atr1   0.945
Atr2   0.838
Atr3   0.851
Atr4   0.874
Atr5   0.987
Atr7   0.532
Atr8   0.906
Atr9   0.963
Atr10  0.855
Atr11  0.976
Atr12  0.865
Atr13  0.928
Atr14  0.885
Atr15  0.941
Atr16  0.904
Atr17  0.979
Atr18  0.915
Atr19  0.986
Atr20  0.907
Atr21  0.945
Atr22  0.905
Atr23  0.972
Atr24  0.892
Atr25  0.954
Atr26  0.892
Atr27  0.943
Atr28  0.903
Atr29  0.980
Atr30  0.890
Atr31  0.925
Atr32  0.906
Atr33  0.972
Atr34  0.944
Atr35  0.997
Atr36  0.990
Atr37  0.936
Atr38  0.974
Atr39  0.953
Atr40  0.975
Atr41  0.971
Atr42  0.818
Atr43  0.668
Atr44  0.911
Atr45  0.685
Atr46  0.615
Atr47  0.778
Atr48  0.720
Atr49  0.853
Atr50  0.865
Atr51  0.825
Atr52  0.758
Atr53  0.818
Atr54  0.944

```
            ML1   ML2
```

SS loadings    42.4 1.023
Proportion Var  0.8 0.019
Cumulative Var  0.8 0.819

where, from my understanding, all the attributes belong to Factor 1 and there is nothing under Factor 2.

Is this a reasonable result? And is there any thing I was doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider three or more factor analysis. I think two-factor analysis is not sufficient.